# How to load data with .out filename using importdata?

Tags: matlab, import

I have .out files that have a slightly strange format with some strings as well as numerical data. If I try to import these .out files using *importdata*, I just get an empty double. However, I can import these files using *importdata* if I rename the files to .dat. Is there a way of telling MATLAB to read .out files as if they were .dat files? Here is an example:

```
Optimizer metric (    0.0000%):       0.4728620
   0.00000000E+00   1.51265733E-03   2.37895687E-04         65
   0.00000000E+00   1.42127093E-03   8.50384026E-04        129
   0.00000000E+00   9.70161923E-04   1.53099383E-03         22
   0.00000000E+00   7.77171709E-18   3.28125000E-03        173
   0.00000000E+00  -9.78525388E-04   1.54419205E-03         36
   0.00000000E+00  -1.44808737E-03   8.66429008E-04         88
   0.00000000E+00  -1.60526901E-03   2.52460729E-04        141


Optimizer metric (   -0.0300%):       0.4790671
  -3.00000000E-02   1.48622036E-03   2.02852233E-04        142
  -3.00000000E-02   1.30349178E-03   6.76857256E-04         85
  -3.00000000E-02   8.47690479E-04   1.16095956E-03         27
  -3.00000000E-02   4.05107907E-18   1.48437500E-03         38
  -3.00000000E-02  -1.01354296E-03   1.38810382E-03         99
  -3.00000000E-02  -1.28962484E-03   6.69656647E-04        159
  -3.00000000E-02  -1.56362767E-03   2.13417454E-04        124


Optimizer metric (    0.0300%):       0.4272724
   3.00000000E-02   1.77325173E-03   2.90410157E-04         67
   3.00000000E-02   1.79030135E-03   1.11547478E-03        138
   3.00000000E-02   1.29147233E-03   2.12231439E-03         51
   3.00000000E-02   9.38223310E-18   4.12500000E-03         81
   3.00000000E-02  -1.26710493E-03   2.08227072E-03        158
   3.00000000E-02  -1.94943925E-03   1.21462809E-03        194
   3.00000000E-02  -1.92744754E-03   3.15663214E-04        170
```

Comment: The format is just a format, what is important is for Matlab to correctly read every line of your data and delimit the data line by line (or block by block) with the correct delimiter, in your case, you need to specify the exact format of the .out file, once you have this, it doesn't matter you convert it in to .csv or .dat; Matlab will read in what you tell it to read in.

Comment: @GameOfThrows The format is complicated with multiple blocks and thus it is hard to specify. I can work with what _importdata_ gives me when I use a .dat extension. All I want to do is get exactly the same thing just with a different extension.

Comment: a quick look at http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/supported-file-formats.html?refresh=true shows that Matlab does not support .out format, you will have to convert it into csv or dat. So if simply changing the extension of the file to .dat works for you, you might have to do this manually, or automated if you write something in other programming language. Matlab isn't exactly fabulous when everything is in functions and have restrained format for running each function

Comment: @GameOfThrows I don't understand why the file extension should make any difference to Matlab. It's literally just a name.

Comment: every function in Matlab is written with input format checks to keep everything nice,tidy and working. This prevents mistakes and ensures standards. This is the standard when it comes to function programming

Comment: @GameOfThrows `shows that Matlab does not support .out format, you will have to convert it into csv or dat` is absolutely not correct. If the file format is not of a format MATLAB recognizes it will be treated as a delimited text file.

Comment: @excaza thanks for the knowledge. I didn't know that, so if it treats it as a text file, then you should be able to read it in line by line and parse using own delimiter settings?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - just tried a couple of simple string + numeric file, '.dat' or '.out' load the same with `importdata`.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce this error. The code for `importdata` is not obfuscated, I would recommend using `open importdata` and running through it with the debugger to see the differences between handling of your two files. I see no difference between my `*.dat` and `*.out` files.

Comment: If you would add few lines of your .out files, it is easier to understand your problem.

Comment: @Lati What's the best way of doing that?

Comment: @GameOfThrows Yes, that is an option. However, it lacks the elegance of a one line call and also doesn't answer the explicit question on why the function is returning different data based on the file extension.

Comment: @danm Just give us enough to understand the format.  e.g. is there a header, how many columns, what is the delimiter, are there additional features like comment lines mixed in, etc.

Comment: @danm your sample data works for me with `importdata` as both `*.dat` and `*.out`

Comment: @danm Your data is not regularly formatted so I don't think importdata will work for you. In your case I would read line by line using fgetl and use sscanf to classify each line